# How to move sublist fields created from User Event script

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I added a sublist field on a transaction. For instance a Sales Order. When you add the field via user event script, it positions the field at the end of the sublist. Is there a way to position the field? This can't be accomplished in the UI as the field is added via script. It's a select type field, so I am trying to modify the list values with client script and can only do that if the field is created in my user even script. My code works perfectly fine, it's just the field is at the end of the sublist line(far right and have to scroll). I am using SuiteScript 1.0 but am open to using 2.0 if I need to.

Answer (score 0):

This is for suitescript 2.0

This has sort of turned into two questions so I will give an answer for one and then the solution, for clarity. The short answer is you cannot move a sublist field when created in a user event (however there is a solution to that.)

you can add a sublist field by getting the sublist and using the sublist.addField method.

```
function beforeLoad(context){
    var form = context.form;
    var sublist = form.getSublist({
        id : 'item'
    });

    sublist.addField({
      id: 'fieldid you want to use for script reference ect.',
      type: serverWidget.FieldType.CHECKBOX, //any supported TYPE
      label: 'Label users will see in sublist'
    });
}
```

If done this way, there will be a new column on the end of the items sublist that cannot be moved.

To be able to move the location of the column do the following.
Navigate to

- Customization
- Lists, Records, & Fields
- Transaction Line Fields

add a new field and apply to the sublist you want it used on.

you can assign and id which will be prefixed with custcol so start your id with an _ and give it a name.

Once this is complete you can access the field by id and change the value in your user event script before load

```
function beforeLoad(context){
    var form = context.form;
    var sublist = form.getSublist({
        id : 'item'
    });

    sublist.setSublistValue({
       id: 'customcol_id_created_in_ui',
       line: 1, //line you want to access if needing to set all you will have to loop through and set each one.
       value: "your value" 
    });
}
```

If you go to the API reference and look at the ui/serverWidget module and navigate to sublist you can find all of the methods and options for manipulating sublist there.

Answer (score -1):

In SuiteScript 2.x you would use the N/ui/serverWidget module, create the field and then use the `Form.insertField(options)` method, passing in the field you created as `options.field` and the existing field which you want to insert your field before as `options.nextfield`.  Note that `Form` refers to the form object passed to the user event script in the scriptContext.

i don't believe there is a SS1.0 equivalent.

Comment: Is this answer relevant to the question specifically? I believe the Form.insertField() method is only for body level fields, not sublist fields like in the question.

Comment: Looks like you're right, @ToddGrimm.  As a general rule I test any advice I give here before submitting, but I just tested this and it's failing silently.  Not sure if something changed with the API behavior (which wouldn't surprise me) or if I missed the fact that the question specifically asks about sublists (which would surprise me even less). :)

Comment: No worries, just happened to be hunting down an answer to this question for a while and have seen the "insertField()" method offered as a potential solution several places but never anyone responding with confirmation that it worked. And like you, all my testing resulted in silent failures, so I just wanted to confirm.